# Counting on a matrix

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, matrices, counting

I have an $n \times m$ matrix, and fill it with numbers of $1 \dots k$.

If a matrix can be turned into another matrix by exchanging its lines and exchanging its columns, the two matrices are considered to be the same.

I know that I can easily computed the numbers of the different matrices out in $O((n\times m)^k)$ time, but is there any better algorithms for this problems?

Also, I am wondering whether $\texttt{Burnside's lemma}$ or $\texttt{Polya's Theorem}$ work here. I am having no ideas with them.

Comment: Are you asking number of symmetric matrices having element in range 1 to K? If it's so, then you just need to calculate $k^{n(n+1)/2}$.

Comment: In order to use Burnside's lemma, you should consider every permutation of the rows and the columns ($n!\times n!$) and find the number of matrices that are unchanged under this permutation. Since they are two permutations are intertwined, a super fast solution is not straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from [here](https://franklinvp.github.io/2020-06-05-PolyaFooBar/).

## The mathematics

Consider the group  $G=S_w\times S_h$, where $S_w$ and $S_h$ are the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) of the sets $W=\{1,2,3,\ldots,w\}$ and $H=\{1,2,3,\ldots,h\}$ with $w$ and $h$ elements, respectively. The group $G$ acts on the set $X=W\times H$, which we view as the set of indexes of the entries of the matrices.

Each matrix is a function $f:X\to S$, and element $f\in S^X$.

So, the problem consists of computing the cardinality

$$\left|S^X/G\right|$$

### Cycle index polynomial of a group of permutations

For a permutation group $G$ acting on a set $X=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ define the polynomial

$$Z(G,s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_n)=|G|^{-1}\sum_{g\in G}\prod_{k=1}^{n}s_k^{c_k(g)}$$

where $c_k(g)$ is the number of cycles of length $k$ in the cycle decomposition of the permutation $g$.

**Polya's enumeration theorem** tell us that

$$\left|S^X/G\right|=Z(G,s,s,\ldots,s)=|G|^{-1}\sum_{g\in G}s^{c_k(g)}$$

### Cycle index of the Cartesian product

In our case, $G$ is the Cartesian product $S_w\times S_h$. In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390015L) they prove the following formula

$$Z(G_1\times G_2,s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{n_1\cdot n_2}) = Z(G_1,s_1,\ldots,s_{n_1})\otimes Z(G_1,s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{n_2})$$
where the product $\otimes$ (In the paper they use the symbol [text reference mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_mark)) of polynomials is defined by:

If

$$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)=\sum a_{i_1i_2\ldots i_m}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\dotsm x_m^{i_m}\text{ and }g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum b_{j_1j_2\ldots j_n}x_1^{j_1}x_2^{j_2}\dotsm x_n^{j_n}$$

then

$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)\otimes g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\sum a_{i_1i_2\ldots i_m}b_{j_1j_2\ldots j_n}\times\prod_{\substack{1\leq r\leq m\\1\leq s\leq n}}(x_{r}^{i_l}\otimes x_{s}^{j_s})$$

where

$$x_{r}^{i_l}\otimes x_{s}^{j_s} = x_{\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)}^{\gcd(r,s)i_rj_s}$$

### Cycle index of the symmetric group

For the case of the symmetric group $S_n$ acting on $\\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\\}$ we have

$$Z(S_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_kZ(S_{n-k})$$

or explicitly

$$Z(S_n,s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n)=\sum_{r_1+2r_2+3r_3+\ldots nr_n=n}\frac{s_1^{r_1}s_2^{r_2}\dotsm s_n^{r_n}}{1^{r_1}r_1!2^{r_2}r_2!\dotsm n^{r_n}r_n!}$$

### Solution of the problem

Combining the results above we obtain that the number of classes of $w\times h$ matrices on $s$ symbols up to permutations of the rows and columns is
$$N=\frac{1}{w!h!}\sum_{\substack{i\in P(W)\\j\in P(H)}}\frac{w!}{1^{i_1}i_1!2^{i_2}i_2!\dotsm w^{i_w}i_w!}\frac{h!}{1^{j_1}j_1!2^{j_2}j_2!\dotsm h^{j_h}j_h!}s^{\sum_{\substack{a\in i\\b\in j}}\gcd(a,b)}$$
where the outer sums runs over the partitions $i=(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_w)$ and $j=(j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_h)$ of $w$ and $h$, respectively. This is, $i_1+2i_2+\ldots+wi_w=w$ and $j_1+2j_2+\ldots+hj_h=h$. The inner sums run over the elements $a$ and $b$ of the partitions $i$ and $j$. This is, $a$ takes the value $1$, $i_1$ times, the value $2$ $i_2$ times, and so on and likewise $b$ takes the value $1$ $j_1$ times, the value $2$ $j_2$ times, etc.

## Implementation

As seen in the final formula, we need to compute:

1. [Partitions of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))
2. Greatest common divisors (gcd) of many numbers.
3. [Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of many numbers.

For these, we can do:

1. To compute all partitions one can use the iterative algorithms [here](https://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html).
2. An efficient way to compute `gcd` one could use Euclidean algorithm. However, since we are going to need the gcd of all pairs of numbers in a range and each one many times. It is better to pre-compute the full table of gcd all at once by *dynamic programming*. If `a>b`, then `gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b,b)`. This recurrence equation allows to compute gcd of larger pairs in terms of that of smaller pairs. In the table, one has the initial values `gcd(1,a)=gcd(a,1)=1` and `gcd(a,a)=a`, for all `a`.
3. The same happens for factorials. The formula will require the factorials of all numbers in a range many times each. So, it is better to compute them all from the bottom up using that `n! = n(n-1)!` and `0!=1!=1`.
4. The powers of $s$, which are also needed repeatedly in the sum could also be pre-computed.

An implementation in Python could look like [this](https://github.com/franklinvp/foobar/blob/master/foobar2020/solutionProblem1.py). Feel free to improve it.